# How to implement a 2D Gaussian on a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, gaussian

I have a 2D NumPy array of size 10 by 10, in which I am trying to implement a 2D Gaussian distribution on it so that I can use the new column as a feature in my ML model. The center (the peak of the Gaussian distribution) should be at (3, 5) of the 2D NumPy array. Is there any way to do this in Python? I have also included a heatmap of my np array.

Here is my data:

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
    my_np_list = [310.90634 , 287.137   , 271.87973 , 266.6     , 271.87973 ,
           287.137   , 310.90634 , 341.41458 , 377.02936 , 416.44254 ,
           266.6     , 238.4543  , 219.844   , 213.28001 , 219.844   ,
           238.4543  , 266.6     , 301.62347 , 341.41458 , 384.496   ,
           226.2176  , 192.248   , 168.61266 , 159.96    , 168.61266 ,
           192.248   , 226.2176  , 266.6     , 310.90634 , 357.68146 ,
           192.248   , 150.81174 , 119.22715 , 106.64001 , 119.22715 ,
           150.81174 , 192.248   , 238.4543  , 287.137   , 337.2253  ,
           168.61266 , 119.22715 ,  75.40587 ,  53.320004,  75.40587 ,
           119.22715 , 168.61266 , 219.844   , 271.87973 , 324.33292 ,
           159.96    , 106.64001 ,  53.320004,   0.      ,  53.320004,
           106.64001 , 159.96    , 213.28001 , 266.6     , 319.92    ,
           168.61266 , 119.22715 ,  75.40587 ,  53.320004,  75.40587 ,
           119.22715 , 168.61266 , 219.844   , 271.87973 , 324.33292 ,
           192.248   , 150.81174 , 119.22715 , 106.64001 , 119.22715 ,
           150.81174 , 192.248   , 238.4543  , 287.137   , 337.2253  ,
           226.2176  , 192.248   , 168.61266 , 159.96    , 168.61266 ,
           192.248   , 226.2176  , 266.6     , 310.90634 , 357.68146 ,
           266.6     , 238.4543  , 219.844   , 213.28001 , 219.844   ,
           238.4543  , 266.6     , 301.62347 , 341.41458 , 384.496   ]
    
    my_np_array = np.array(my_np_list).reshape(10, 10)
    plt.imshow(my_np_array, interpolation='none')
    plt.show()
    
    
    size = 100
    store_center = (3, 5)
    i_center = 3
    j_center = 5
```

[image]

I tried the scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.pdf on my array, but it didn't work.

```
    import scipy
    from scipy import stats
    
    my_np_array = my_np_array.reshape(-1)
    y = scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(my_np_array, mean=2, cov=0.5)
    
    y = y.reshape(10,10)
    
    yy = np.dot(y.T,y)
```

Comment: When you say "implement a PDF" what do you actually mean? Do you want to optimize for parameters of fit on a two-dimensional Gaussian? `multivariate_normal` doesn't do that; it generates a new distribution.

Comment: @Reinderien I can see your point. I don't want that. I want a distribution which is dependent on my original data. In other words, the code provided by Frederick does not account for the original data, except its shape.  If I bring another np_array with the same center at [3, 5], the result using this method would be the same and I dont want that. Is there a better method to use?

Comment: Do you want a new distribution "fit to" your original data?

Comment: @Reinderien yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a 2-Gaussian of best fit.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize

my_np_list = [
    310.90634 , 287.137   , 271.87973 , 266.6     , 271.87973 ,
    287.137   , 310.90634 , 341.41458 , 377.02936 , 416.44254 ,
    266.6     , 238.4543  , 219.844   , 213.28001 , 219.844   ,
    238.4543  , 266.6     , 301.62347 , 341.41458 , 384.496   ,
    226.2176  , 192.248   , 168.61266 , 159.96    , 168.61266 ,
    192.248   , 226.2176  , 266.6     , 310.90634 , 357.68146 ,
    192.248   , 150.81174 , 119.22715 , 106.64001 , 119.22715 ,
    150.81174 , 192.248   , 238.4543  , 287.137   , 337.2253  ,
    168.61266 , 119.22715 ,  75.40587 ,  53.320004,  75.40587 ,
    119.22715 , 168.61266 , 219.844   , 271.87973 , 324.33292 ,
    159.96    , 106.64001 ,  53.320004,   0.      ,  53.320004,
    106.64001 , 159.96    , 213.28001 , 266.6     , 319.92    ,
    168.61266 , 119.22715 ,  75.40587 ,  53.320004,  75.40587 ,
    119.22715 , 168.61266 , 219.844   , 271.87973 , 324.33292 ,
    192.248   , 150.81174 , 119.22715 , 106.64001 , 119.22715 ,
    150.81174 , 192.248   , 238.4543  , 287.137   , 337.2253  ,
    226.2176  , 192.248   , 168.61266 , 159.96    , 168.61266 ,
    192.248   , 226.2176  , 266.6     , 310.90634 , 357.68146 ,
    266.6     , 238.4543  , 219.844   , 213.28001 , 219.844   ,
    238.4543  , 266.6     , 301.62347 , 341.41458 , 384.496   ,
]

my_np_array = np.array(my_np_list).reshape(10, -1)


def gaussian2(xy: np.ndarray, a: float, b: float, c: float, d: float, e: float, f: float) -> np.ndarray:
    x, y = xy

    z = (
        a - b
        * np.exp(-((x - c)/d)**2)
        * np.exp(-((y - e)/f)**2)
    )
    return z


xy = np.stack(
    np.meshgrid(
        np.arange(my_np_array.shape[1]),
        np.arange(my_np_array.shape[0]),
    )
).reshape((2, -1))

param, _ = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(
    f=gaussian2,
    xdata=xy,
    ydata=my_np_array.ravel(),
    p0=(400, 400,
        3, 1,
        5, 1)
)
print(param)
zfit = gaussian2(xy, *param).reshape(my_np_array.shape)

fig, (ax_act, ax_fit) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
ax_act.imshow(my_np_array)
ax_fit.imshow(zfit)
plt.show()
```

```
[447.47305265 394.42329346   3.02857599   5.53214092   4.98984104
   5.56048623]
```

[image: best fit]

It's too broad, so if you want a better fit you need to use something that isn't Gaussian. For instance, modified exponents of about 1.7 and 1.8 provide for an excellent fit - discounting your peak "0" which looks fake to me.

```
def gaussian2(xy: np.ndarray, a: float, b: float, c: float, d: float, e: float, f: float, g: float, h: float) -> np.ndarray:
    x, y = xy

    z = (
        a - b
        * np.exp(-np.abs((x - c)/d)**e)
        * np.exp(-np.abs((y - f)/g)**h)
    )
    return z


param, _ = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(
    f=gaussian2,
    xdata=xy,
    ydata=my_np_array.ravel(),
    p0=(400, 400,
        3, 5, 2,
        5, 5, 2)
)
```

```
[482.96976151 441.22504655   3.01091214   6.11061124   1.79338408
   5.00625763   6.27235212   1.69061652]
```

[image: non-gaussian fit]

This will improve even further if you exclude the fake peak from the fit:

```
z_flat = my_np_array.ravel()
not_zero, = np.nonzero(z_flat)
z_flat = z_flat[not_zero]
xy = xy[:, not_zero]
# ...

zfit = np.zeros_like(my_np_array)
x, y = xy
zfit[y, x] = gaussian2(xy, *param)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd like to calculate a 2D Gaussian PDF with the same shape (e.g. 10 by 10) of the data you have in `my_np_array`. The provided code calculates a 1D distribution as the input array is reshaped to 1D, with only one relevant mean value, and one cov value. Instead, create a grid of index values (all i, j pairs), and use `i_center` and `j_center` as the two mean values of the 2D distribution along the `i` and `j` dimensions, respectively:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

my_np_list = [310.90634 , 287.137   , 271.87973 , 266.6     , 271.87973 ,
       287.137   , 310.90634 , 341.41458 , 377.02936 , 416.44254 ,
       266.6     , 238.4543  , 219.844   , 213.28001 , 219.844   ,
       238.4543  , 266.6     , 301.62347 , 341.41458 , 384.496   ,
       226.2176  , 192.248   , 168.61266 , 159.96    , 168.61266 ,
       192.248   , 226.2176  , 266.6     , 310.90634 , 357.68146 ,
       192.248   , 150.81174 , 119.22715 , 106.64001 , 119.22715 ,
       150.81174 , 192.248   , 238.4543  , 287.137   , 337.2253  ,
       168.61266 , 119.22715 ,  75.40587 ,  53.320004,  75.40587 ,
       119.22715 , 168.61266 , 219.844   , 271.87973 , 324.33292 ,
       159.96    , 106.64001 ,  53.320004,   0.      ,  53.320004,
       106.64001 , 159.96    , 213.28001 , 266.6     , 319.92    ,
       168.61266 , 119.22715 ,  75.40587 ,  53.320004,  75.40587 ,
       119.22715 , 168.61266 , 219.844   , 271.87973 , 324.33292 ,
       192.248   , 150.81174 , 119.22715 , 106.64001 , 119.22715 ,
       150.81174 , 192.248   , 238.4543  , 287.137   , 337.2253  ,
       226.2176  , 192.248   , 168.61266 , 159.96    , 168.61266 ,
       192.248   , 226.2176  , 266.6     , 310.90634 , 357.68146 ,
       266.6     , 238.4543  , 219.844   , 213.28001 , 219.844   ,
       238.4543  , 266.6     , 301.62347 , 341.41458 , 384.496   ]

my_np_array = np.array(my_np_list).reshape(10, 10)
plt.imshow(my_np_array, interpolation='none')
plt.show()

i_center = 3
j_center = 5

# Create grid of i, j points
# See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html
j_n, i_n = my_np_array.shape
j_grid, i_grid = np.mgrid[0:j_n, 0:i_n]
pos = np.dstack((j_grid, i_grid))

# Create 2D Gaussian PDF values for grid
rv = multivariate_normal([j_center, i_center], [[0.5, 0], [0, 0.5]])
y = rv.pdf(pos)

# Plot 2D PDF values
plt.imshow(y, interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

[image: 2D Gaussian PDF output]

The pdf is evaluated over all the j and i pairs in `pos`, and the `j_center` and `i_center` values provide the position where the peak in the 2D Gaussian distribution occurs (i.e. the mean values). The `cov` matrix only has the one value provided on the diagonals as it looks like the data has the same cov along the j and i axes.

Comment: Thanks for the guide. If I bring another np_array with the same center at [3, 5],, the result of the Gaussian distribution would be the same, isn't it? I mean the result is not dependent on the original array distribution. How to generate a new distribution which is dependent on the original data?

Comment: Yes, it would have the same center, and would have the same distribution width along the `i` and `j` axes, unless you specified a different `cov` matrix. You could try estimating the `cov` for each new `np_array`, then they'd be different widths but have the same center. Without more context about what you''re trying to do, I don't think I can help anymore than this